# Ruby, how to take a specific percentage of elements of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

In a testing context I need to take a specific percentage of the elements of an array.

The specifications of my request can be described in this test:

```
def test_percent_elements
  array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

  assert_equal([], array.percent_elements(0))
  assert_equal([1], array.percent_elements(1))
  assert_equal([1], array.percent_elements(10))
  assert_equal([1,2], array.percent_elements(11))
  assert_equal([1,2,3,4,5], array.percent_elements(50))
  assert_equal([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], array.percent_elements(100))
end
```

Which is the best way to solve this in Ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd write:

```
class Array
  def percent_elements(percent)
    take((size * percent / 100.0).ceil)
  end
end
```

Comment: I love one liners like this. +1.

Comment: or `take (size * percent / 100.0).ceil`

Comment: Applied some proposed changes. I prefer to put the parens (unless writing some DSL constructions)

Answer (score 0):

My actual approach is this:

```
class Array
  def percent_elements(percent)
    total = self.length
    elements = ((total * percent) / 100.to_f).ceil
    self[0, elements]
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this the one you are looking for? means did you get your answer?

Comment: As a review I'd say: 1) Don't write explicit `self`s. 2) No need to create `total` since `length`/`size` are already there. 3) `100.to_f` -> `100.0`. 4) `self[0, elements]` -> `take(elements)`. 5) It's a debatable whether this method qualifies as generic enough to be added to `Array`.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu this was my first approach, I was looking for a more beauty solution as the accepted answer.

Comment: @fguillen yeah! then your approach should go to your post not in answer.